# I need syncfusion ReportViewer for Lightswitch silverlight client

Tags: silverlight, reportviewer, visual-studio-lightswitch, syncfusion

I am looking for download url for ReportViewer extension for visual studio lightswitch silverlight client made by syncfusion.
I already used it before, but I lost the setup file.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syncfusion stopped providing LightSwitch Silverlight setup from v14.4.0.20. Lastly we have provided this setup in v14.4.0.15.

https://help.syncfusion.com/common/essential-studio/essential-studio-retired-products

It can be downloaded from your accounts and download page in Syncfusion website.

https://www.syncfusion.com/account/downloads